# Capturing repeated groups into different groups

Tags: python, regex

I want to capture repeated groups in Python as a separate list:

```
match = re.match(r'!((?:abc|123)+)!', '!abc123abc!').groups()
print(match)
print(len(match))
```

This gives back a tuple with a single element:

```
('abc123abc',)
1
```

How can I get the following output?

```
('abc', '123', 'abc',)
3
```

Following [this helpful article on capturing repeated groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html) I now understand the earlier problem I had, trying to repeat a capturing group instead of capturing a repeated group. But still I don't understand how or if it is possible to capture **different groups** for better post-processing.

Please note that I cannot do without the pre-/suffix, because this also contains multiple capturing groups. My actual use case differs a little bit from this MWE, but should be clear enough.

Comment: Try `>>> re.findall(r'abc|123', x)`   `['abc', '123', 'abc']`.

Comment: This would work, but in the case I want to use it, I cannot do without the pre-/suffix, which also contains several capturing groups.

Comment: `re.findall` returns a `list`. You cannot use `groups()` on `re.findall`. Are you talking about `re.search` ? Note, `re.match` will match from `start`

Comment: Use PyPi regex model and grab `.captures(1)` with `r'!(abc|123)+!'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This gives back `['abc123abc']`, not `['abc', '123', 'abc']`.

Comment: @hansolo I fixed my earlier response, because I noticed too late my erroneous usage of `groups()`.

Comment: No way, `regex.match(r'!(abc|123)+!', '!abc123abc!').captures(1)` [yields expected output](https://rextester.com/RFXH47168), `['abc', '123', 'abc']`

Comment: Sorry but I skipped your change on the regex. Thank you it works!

Answer (score 0):

This resembles the correct answer by @WiktorStribiżew while staying more easily comparable to my original question

```
import regex as re
match = re.match(r'!(abc|123)+!', '!abc123abc!').captures(1)
print(match)
print(len(match))
```

Which correctly outputs

```
['abc', '123', 'abc']
3
```

This works, because the `regex` module (not to be confused with Python's internal `re` module) handles groups differently when using the `capture()` method, i.e. not overwriting them (as outlined in the article in my original question), but rather append them, not overwriting the index. This can be followed in the section *Notes on named capture groups* in the [`regex` package's official documentation](https://pypi.org/project/regex/).